# Why won't my function execute (ASP.NET)?

Tags: asp.net, function, execute

Basically I have a aspx page function that will not seem to activate. I've created a function that's supposed to run on selectedindexchange of a dropdownmenu.

```
<asp:TableCell>Credit Card Type: <asp:DropDownList
        id="DropDownCredit"
         OnSelectedIndexChanged="creditType"
        Runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem Text="Select" Value="Empty" />    
        <asp:ListItem Text="Visa" Value="Visa" />    
        <asp:ListItem Text="Mastercard" Value="Mastercard" />   
        <asp:ListItem Text="Discover" Value="Discover" />         
        <asp:ListItem Text="American Express" Value="American Express" />  
    </asp:DropDownList>
```

There as you can see I added my function name to run when they select something. Now my function itself is extremely simple.

```
Protected Sub creditType()
        If DropDownCredit.SelectedIndex.ToString.StartsWith("A") Then
            TextBoxCardNumberAmerican.Enabled = True
        Else
            TextBoxCardNumberOthers.Enabled = True

        End If
    End Sub
```

By the way I have set the two textboxes mentioned in the above function to disabled inititally, so only if one is correct then it is enabled. I am going to guess that the string isn't being interpreted properly. Any help would be great thankyou.

Answer (score 1):

Two things: Your creditYpe method has the wrong signature it should be:

```
    Protected Sub creditType(Object o, EventArgs e)
```

..and add the AutoPostBack="true" property to your asp control

```
    Credit Card Type: <asp:DropDownList
        id="DropDownCredit"
         OnSelectedIndexChanged="creditType"
         AutoPostBack="true"
        Runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem Text="Select" Value="Empty" />    
        <asp:ListItem Text="Visa" Value="Visa" />    
        <asp:ListItem Text="Mastercard" Value="Mastercard" />   
        <asp:ListItem Text="Discover" Value="Discover" />         
        <asp:ListItem Text="American Express" Value="American Express" />  
    </asp:DropDownList>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should add the AutoPostBack="True" property to the dropdown
only then the server side sub will be executed

Answer (score 0):

Please set the

```
AutoPostBack="True"
```

On the dropdown. Like this:

```
<asp:DropDownList id="DropDownCredit" 
OnSelectedIndexChanged="creditType" AutoPostBack="True" Runat="server">
```

The the event will fire